# Creating complex probabilities within Java

Tags: java, probability

I'm trying to create a baseball simulation game within java. I'm utilizing instances of 'pitches' as the the iteration for my system. Within this, I have several different possibilities for the outcome. Hit, miss(strike), foul ball(no effect). I created an array of players from another class that read in specific attributes of my players that I design. The only attributes I'm trying to utilize currently are the power of the hitters and their consistency. I'm using random numbers to generate a certain and depending on where that value lies, determines whether it is a ball or a strike. The 'ball' logic is simple and works effectively; however, I'm only receiving counts of balls for the hitters. I'm stuck on how to implement the logic of probability of a strike(a missed swing) or a hit in regards to the pitch being a strike. The constructor I'm using for the player goes as follows

```
Player a = new Player(false, false, true, 10, 20, 0.75, true, null);
```

you can ignore the false's and true's and null, just pay attention to the numbers
the first number(10) indicates the speed, not relevant. 
The second number(20) indicates the power.
The third indicates the consistency of the hitter.

I apologize if this may be confusing or too elementary, I've only been programming for a little over a month. All help would be greatly appreciated. Currently the only thing printing for me looks a little like

```
Press 'p' to initiate pitches
p
Ball count is: (0,0)
Ball count is: (0,0)
Ball count is: (0,0)
Ball count is: (0,0)
Ball! 
Ball count is: (1,0)
Ball count is: (1,0)
Ball! 
Ball count is: (2,0)
Ball count is: (2,0)
Ball count is: (2,0)
Ball! 
Ball count is: (3,0)
```

I don't understand why the program is only recognizing balls and not describing what is printing as nothing, which I assume to be the foul ball(however its not printing my statement)

Please help, and thank you so much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Press 'p' to initiate pitches");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = kb.nextLine();
if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
{
    int ball = 0;
        int strike = 0;
    //10 instances of pitches
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    double number = Math.random();
    if(number > 0.5)
    {
        ball++;
        if(ball == 4)
        {
        System.out.println("Ball four, take your base");
        break;
        }
        System.out.print("Ball!");
    }
    else if(strike() == true)
    {
       {
            if(isMiss() == true)
        {
            System.out.print(" Strike!");
            strike++;
        }
        else if(isFoul() == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Foul ball!");
        }
        }
        if(strike == 3)
        {
        System.out.print(" Player struck out!");
        break;
        }
            }
    else
    {
        if(isHit() == true)
        {
        System.out.println("The ball was hit!");
        System.out.println(isHit());
        break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" Ball count is: " + "(" + ball + "," + strike + ")");
    }
}
}

public static boolean strike()
{
if(isMiss() == true)
{
        return true;
}
else if(isFoul() == true)
{
        return false;
}
else if(isHit() == true)
{
        return true;
}
return false;
}

public static boolean isHit()
{
double probability = Math.random();
Player a = new Player(false, false, true, 10, 20, 0.75, true, null);
if(a.power > 5)
{
    if(a.consistency > 0.5)
    {
            if(probability > 3 && probability < 6)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(probability > 6 && probability < 9)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(probability > 9 && probability < 12)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("The ball was hit!");
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isMiss()
{
    double probability = Math.random();
    Player a = new Player(false, false, true, 10, 20, 0.75, true, null);
    if(a.power > 5)
    {
        if(a.consistency > 0.5)
        {
            if(probability > 3 && probability < 6)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(probability > 6 && probability < 9)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(probability > 9 && probability < 12)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isFoul()
{
    double probability = Math.random();
    Player a = new Player(false, false, true, 10, 20, 0.75, true, null);
    if(a.power > 5)
    {
        if(a.consistency > 0.5)
        {
            if(probability > 3 && probability < 6)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(probability > 6 && probability < 9)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(probability > 9 && probability < 12)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `probability > 6 return true;`.should probably change this variable name.

Comment: your brackets (`{` and `}`) don't match each other. eg 2x `{` after `else if(strike() == true)`

Answer (score 0):

For strikes:

```
if (Math.random() > consistency) { /* strike! */ }
```

You might want a constant foul ball chance (like if they hit the ball, they have a 10% chance of foul ball:

```
else if (Math.random() < 0.1) { ... }
```

And same for power, but maybe multiply it by 0.3 (since home runs are rare):

```
if (Math.random() < power * 0.3) { ... }
```

Note that for these to work, your consistency and power variables have to be decimals.

For example, 50% consistency would be 0.5. 20% consistency would be 0.2. Similarly, 1 is the maximum amount of power and 0 is really weak. 
0.5 would be in between.

Comment: So, do I implement the constant like public static final double FOUL_BALL = 0.1;   ?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. You should change the variables consistency and power into doubles as well.

Comment: what do I implement in the logic for the if statement where math.random() > consistency?

Comment: Okay so the next two if statements are regarding what? and do I implement them in strike?

Comment: Read what I wrote and it will be pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use your debugger to step through your code as there are many sections which don't make sense to me and I cannot run your code for you using with the Player class (and I cannot make it up as it doesn't make sense ;)

Sections of code which don't make sense are

```
double probability = Math.random();
```

so probability is a number between [0, 1)

```
if(probability > 3 && probability < 6) // always false.
if(probability > 6 && probability < 9) // always false
if(probability > 9 && probability < 12) // always false.

// prints the ball was hit but returns `false` to isHit
System.out.println("The ball was hit!");
}
return false;
```